# I want to remove default theme header and footer from WooCommerce cart and checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, header, cart

I am making a custome theme and i want to add the custom header and footer to cart and checkout page. But, `get_footer('cart')` is not working and it is loading the default header and footer even when i am not calling for header and footer they are still there.

How can we display my custom "footer-cart.php" to the woocommerce cart page? Either with get_footer(); or with `is_cart`  function

Comment: You can add different header and footer in header.php and footer.php by condition is_page(cart) and is_page(checkout)

Comment: The format for footer template names is `footer-{$name}.php` - so your file should be named `footer-cart.php`, and not `footer_cart.php`.

Comment: @CBroe Sorry, It was a mistake, I have named it "footer-cart.php". but it is not working

Comment: Hey, @JahidHasan can you please give me a proper code?

Comment: So where did you actually put this code then? Into a custom page template? And did you actually _assign_ this template to the cart page? Because _"even when i am not calling for header and footer they are still there"_ sounds like this might simply still be using the default page template.

Answer (score 0):

Create like this in your header.php and footer.php file.

```
<?php 
    if(is_page('cart')){

        echo 'cart page header'; // include your cart page header file

    }elseif(is_page('checkout')){

        echo 'checkout page header'; // include your checkout page header file

    }else{

        echo 'defult header'; // include your defult page header file

    }
?>
```